# How to find all groups in a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this

```
[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]
```

and I want to group them and then find the length of each group. So the result will be like that:

```
[[2,0],[3,1].....[4,1]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l =  [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]
>>> [(len(list(g)), k) for k,g in itertools.groupby(l)]
[(2, 0), (3, 1), (3, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0), (4, 1)]
```

Comment: You can also use [ilen](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/seqs.html#ilen) from [funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy) library instead of `len(list(...))` for speed.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [7]: import itertools

In [8]: [[sum(1 for _ in g),v] for v,g in itertools.groupby(l)]
Out[8]: [[2, 0], [3, 1], [3, 0], [2, 1], [2, 0], [4, 1]]
```

Where `l` is your input list.